# Can I create a mysql database where the data is imported from excel files then displayed through a UI

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to know if it would be possible to import an excel file into a databse? The columns for the MySQL database would have the same columns that the excel file would have **and** the title of the excel file.

So for example if I have a file named `BL#123456` I would like to be able to take the data in that file and have it outputted to a user as `"x y z a b c BL#"`.

I think I understand the process of data import from excel into MySQL the only thing is the file name to appear along side the columns.

Also I would be using a PHP script to import the data.

EDIT: How do I get it to import the file name as well as the data

Comment: What have you done so far? Into which problems did you run?

Comment: Since you've only asked one question: yes, you can import a .CSV dump from Excel into MySQL. But you wouldn't want to do it with arbitrary data.

Comment: Currently, I can import directly through phpmyadmin, however the file name BL#123456 isn't added into the table. I guess to be a bit more clear, we use BL #'s to track RMA products, and within each BL spreadsheet are several items with serial numbers comments parts model# etc and i want to be able to take all the info put it in the db ALONG with the BL# to reference. So that the end user can search by BL# and get all that information or seach by serial# and see that it is set across many different BL#'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work if you did this?

1) create your table (include an additional column for the file name)
2) import a spreadsheet (you probably have collected the file name at this point, so stick it in a variable)
3) after importing each spreadsheet, run an update on your table `UPDATE TABLE set fileName = $variable WHERE filename is null`